# Angular 6 to 12 Migration Issues

Tags: angular

I am getting below error after i upgraded from Angular 6 to Angular 12

```
styles.css - Error: styles.css from Css Minimizer
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
    at Processor.normalize (C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:168:15)
```

Can anyone help me what can be reason for this ?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the node_modules dir and npm i everything new? Maybe there is still an older version somewhere in there.

Comment: @IynxSevn i tried also tried to clear cache still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Processor can't make sense of the Object being passed to it. I just recently had something very similar from a migration as well so might suspect some version mismatch. For my case the problem was caused by old package_lock.

Just the get this out of the way. Remove packacge-lock and node_modules `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`, add compatible postcss and install other packages as well `npm install -D postcss && npm install`.

You could also go over some migration steps so see if you missed something. https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=6.0-12.0